# Tkinter - How to change text that were created by for loop?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a button and item count text created in a loop and I don't know how to make it that when click use button it will change the text that belongs to that function instead of the last one.

```
for key,value in Char.getRedSkill().items():
    text = skillCanvas.create_text(320, y5, text=key,
                                   font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='w')
    countText = skillCanvas.create_text(600, y5, text=value,
                                        font=("Helvetica", 15), anchor='w')
    useRedBtn.append(Button(skillCanvas, text="USE",
                            command=lambda key=key: useSkill(key,value,root),
                            font=("Helvetica", 10)).place(x=630, y=y5-15))
    y5 += 30
```

This is the screenshot of my program when I click use "Common Precision Strike" instead of deducting by 1, it changes the "Rare Thunder Bolt"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Please provide a runnable [mre]. Note that you are appending `None` to `useRedBtn` each iteration of the `for` loop because that is what the `place()` method always returns.

Comment: You can change the text of a Tk button at any moment by using: button.config(text="hello")

Comment: If I use  button.config(text="hello")  wouldn't it change the "use" to "hello" instead?

Comment: The `Canvas` text object `countText` doesn't "belong" to the function. In order for the function to change it, the text object's id—`countText`—would need to be passed to it as an argument *or* there must be some other way to determine that from what is already being passed as arguments in the `lambda`.